# How to show ChangeLog Alert only for certain app versions?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to show a Changelog when the app is launched where i would illustrate the user the last update news, when the user closes that view i must save the info about it so i would be able to prevent it opening again (If the new version of the app doesn't requires it again as not all versions might require the Changelog to be shown).

So call this function in my `MainActivity`

```
private void checkFirstRun(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
    final String PREFS_NAME = "FirstRun";
    final String PREF_CHANGELOG_ALERT = "changelog";
    final String PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY = "version_code";
    final int DOESNT_EXIST = -1;

    int currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedVersionCode = prefs.getInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, DOESNT_EXIST);
    boolean firstTimeChangelog = prefs.getBoolean(PREF_CHANGELOG_ALERT, true);

    if (savedVersionCode < 65) {
        // If the App version is lower than 65 (old shared prefs) i need to migrate them.
        migratePreferences(sharedPreferences);
    }

    if (currentVersionCode == 65 && firstTimeChangelog) {
        // If the App version is 65 (new features and layouts has been added) i need to show a change log activity which informs the user about all the news, but i need to show it only once.
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangelogSlider.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    prefs.edit().putInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, currentVersionCode).apply();
}
```

Then in my `ChangelogSlider.class` once the user press "Got it" i set the `PREF_CHANGELOG_ALERT` to `false`.

But then if like in the version 69 i will need to show that alert again, how should i behave?

Comment: Instead of saving a boolean `firstTimeChangelog`, you could save `lastChangelogVersion` which would be an int, and then if that new version has changelog and the value of the int is smaller show it, and update the value of `lastChangelogVersion` to the latest version number.

Comment: @Vucko just created an answer with a solution like that, check it out :)

Comment: That's cool. Cheers man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Vucko

I've changed the code as following:

```
private void checkFirstRun(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
    final String PREFS_NAME = "FirstRun";
    final String PREF_CHANGELOG_ALERT = "changelog";
    final String PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY = "version_code";
    final int DOESNT_EXIST = -1;
    final int VERSION_WITH_CHANGELOG = 65;

    int currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedVersionCode = prefs.getInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, DOESNT_EXIST);
    int lastChangelogVersion = prefs.getInt(PREF_CHANGELOG_ALERT, VERSION_WITH_CHANGELOG);

    if (savedVersionCode < 65) {
        migratePreferences(sharedPreferences);
    }

    if (savedVersionCode < lastChangelogVersion) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangelogSlider.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    prefs.edit().putInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, currentVersionCode).apply();
}
```

So if i set `VERSION_WITH_CHANGELOG` to an upper version than the current i'd show the ChangeLog else if in the new release i don't need it i just keep the old value.